# I am getting an error 'junit:junit:4.12',

Tags: java, android

when I am trying to run my android App.

error output..

*A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.*

*what is this, how to solve this?*

Comment: did u tried File-> Invalidate caches and Restart ??

Comment: now getting this error 12:33 PM Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: SyncIssue.getMultiLineMessage().
    The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
    To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
    Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (6 s 200 ms)

Comment: ok go to Project-> gradle-wrapper.properties in distributionUrl change to this
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Comment: now getting this error Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'
org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Comment: send some screenshots

Comment: https://paste.pics/df632de077779375bbd317954c9dd628

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231359/discussion-between-krishnan-777-and-d-k).